# I want this to run a Continous ping and give me the output

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Two issues,

I want a constaint ping to the two servers, and output to a .csv file.
The script below only runs twice and the output doesn't work. I'm a power newbie so please go easy.

```
$servers = "server1","server2"
$collection = $()
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
$status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
{
    $status["Results"] = "Up"    
}
else
{
    $status["Results"] = "Down"
}
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
$collection += $serverStatus
}    
$collection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath .\ServerStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? There may be a more appropriate solution which doesn't use PowerShell at all.

Comment: I have two sites that have packet loss. The idea is to find when packet loss happens then try to correlate with other things happening on the network.

Comment: You should be using a purpose-built network monitoring tool like Nagios, Paessler, etc. It's designed for this sort of usage. Don't repeat work that others have done and done very well.

Comment: Thanks but I like the idea of learning Powershell.

Comment: Learning PowerShell is fine. Just pick a more appropriate application for it. You're reinventing the wheel here, with the wrong tooling. Your network infrastructure should be alerting you to packet loss, not a script running off a desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output works fine. Just run the script and then `Invoke-Item ServerStatus.csv`

If you want it to run forever just wrap the whole thing in a while loop:

```
$servers = "server1","server2"
$collection = $()
while(1) {
    foreach ($server in $servers)
    {
        ...
    }    
    $collection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath .\ServerStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: I wanted this to run until I had a user report an issue and just export this out to a .csv file. The problem is that is only outputs the last line. Any ideas?

Comment: you'd have to change the while loop condition to detect when the user reports an issue. This doesn't just output the last line though, if you  declared collection as an array and keep using += like you were before all the information will be in the csv